# Why is adler32(0xFFFFFFFF, "") = 0xE000E?

Tags: hash, zlib

I noticed that zlib's [adler32 function](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Checksum) does not always return the original seed when passed an empty string.  For example:

```
adler32(0xFFFFFFFF,          // seed
        (const Bytef *) "",  // buffer
        0                    // length
       )
```

returns `0xE000E`.  I would think it should return `0xFFFFFFFF` instead.

For most other values, it does return the original seed.  However, for 1965855 numbers from 0 to 0xFFFFFFFF, `adler32` changes the seed when the input string is empty.

Is this a bug or quirky behavior of the implementation, or is the range of the Adler-32 function in fact a subset of [0,0xFFFFFFFF] ?

Note that when the pointer is `NULL`, `adler32` always returns `1` (the initial seed).  This is [documented](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html#Checksum) behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument is not a "seed".  It is the previous adler32 value that is being appended to.

Yes, the range of adler32 is not all 32-bit values.  0xffffffff is not a valid adler32.  The only valid adler32 values are those in which the upper and lower 16-bit halves of the 32-bit value are, when interpreted as integers, both less than 65521.  When you call adler32() with a zero length, it will return the upper and lower halves modulo 65521.

1965855 is 65521*15 + 15*65521 + 15*15, which is the number of 32-bit values with a valid upper half and invalid lower half, plus the number with an invalid upper half and a valid lower half, plus the number with both halves invalid.